# Find NA values in a date range

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have these dates:

```
library(lubridate)
set.seed(50)
myDates <- ymd("2013-07-12") + days(sample(1:100, 20))
df <- data.frame(date=as.Date(myDates), value=sample(1:100, 20))
df[sample(1:20, 5, replace=F), "value"] <- NA

         date value
1  2013-09-21    NA
2  2013-08-25    11
3  2013-08-01    NA
4  2013-09-25    96
5  2013-08-31    55
6  2013-07-17    27
7  2013-09-16    99
8  2013-09-11    66
9  2013-07-16    89
10 2013-07-22    37
11 2013-08-17    NA
12 2013-08-06    56
13 2013-09-07    NA
14 2013-07-19    39
15 2013-08-05    NA
16 2013-09-08    17
17 2013-10-20    54
18 2013-08-12    23
19 2013-10-07    71
20 2013-07-26    98
```

I want to make a function that splits the above date range, and any other date range, into 4 parts. The 4 parts should be the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th quartiles of the date range. Therefore, the function needs to find the earliest date and latest date, then assign each element of the `value` to a quartile. The date range in the above code is this:

```
range(df$date[!is.na(df$date)])
[1] "2013-07-16" "2013-10-20"
```

I then need the function to find the number of NA values in each quartile. Can this be done?

Comment: Why did I get a down vote?

Comment: I didn't vote, but don't understand the question. You can certainly split the dates according to quartile ranges, but I don't know, how you want to handle `NA`s when splitting.

Comment: question edited, let me know if still unclear

Comment: How does one know to which quartile a NA belongs? Shouldn't the vector of dates be ordered?

Comment: Indeed, question further edited

Comment: Your question doesn't match your title. Re: your title, you can get the rows w/ NAs like so: `which(is.na(df$value))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion:

```
# Create data
library(lubridate)
set.seed(50)
myDates <- ymd("2013-07-12") + days(sample(1:100, 20))
df <- data.frame(date=as.Date(myDates), value=sample(1:100, 20))
df[sample(1:20, 5, replace=F), "value"] <- NA

#          date value
# 1  2013-09-21    NA
# 2  2013-08-25    NA
# 3  2013-08-01    70
# 4  2013-09-25    82
# 5  2013-08-31    30
# 6  2013-07-17    NA
# 7  2013-09-16    55
# 8  2013-09-11    NA
# 9  2013-07-16    96
# 10 2013-07-22    34
# 11 2013-08-17    33
# 12 2013-08-06    37
# 13 2013-09-07    39
# 14 2013-07-19    54
# 15 2013-08-05    99
# 16 2013-09-08    NA
# 17 2013-10-20    11
# 18 2013-08-12    59
# 19 2013-10-07    31
# 20 2013-07-26    38

# Proposed solution
myQtle   <- quantile(as.POSIXlt(df$date), probs = 0.25 * 1:4)
myCumVal <- sapply(myQtle,
                   function(qtle, theDates, theValues){
                       sum(is.na(theValues[theDates <= qtle]))},
                   theDates  = as.POSIXlt(df$date),
                   theValues = df$value)

data.frame(qtle  = as.Date(myQtle),
           nb.na = c(myCumVal[1], diff(myCumVal)))

#            qtle nb.na
# 25%  2013-07-30     1
# 50%  2013-08-21     0
# 75%  2013-09-12     3
# 100% 2013-10-20     1
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following sequence should help you wat least with part of the problem (sorry for the clumsiness):

```
df <- df[order(df[, 1] ), ]  # sort by date
df$order <- seq(1:nrow(df))  # assignment of order
quartSize <- nrow(df)/4  # size of quartiles
breakPts <- seq(1, nrow(df), quartSize)  # break points
quant <- rep(0, nrow(df))
for (i in 1:nrow(df))
  quant[i] <- ifelse(df[i, 3] < breakPts[2], 1,
                     ifelse(df[i, 3] < breakPts[3], 2,
                            ifelse(df[i, 3] < breakPts[4], 3, 4)
                     )
  )
df <- cbind(df, quant)
```

If you then run `table(df$quant, is.na(df[, 2]))[, 2]`, you'll get a tally of NAs on each quartile.

The earliest date will be `df[1, ]`; the latest, `df[nrow(df), ]`.

Comment: -1 because splitting date into quartiles is part of question and `quantile()` doesn't work on a date object

Comment: Its already in question: "I want to make a function that splits the above date range, and any other date range, into 4 parts. The 4 parts should be the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th quartiles of the date range"